# Show that there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a+\frac{m}{2^n}\geq b$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $ \mathcal{P} \subset  \mathbb{R}$, $\ \mathcal{P}\neq  \emptyset $ et let $b$ an upper bound of  $\mathcal{P}$
>
> Let $a \in \mathcal{P}$ and let $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ Show that : 
>   $$\exists\ m\in\mathbb{N} \text{ such that: } \quad a+\dfrac{m}{2^n}\geq b$$

I tired

For any integer $m$, we have equivalence $a+\frac{m}{2^n}\geq b\ \Leftrightarrow\ m\geq2^n(b-a)$

Now as ${\mathbb R}$ is Archimedean, there is a natural number $m$ higher than the actual  $2^n(b-a)$

am i right if there any other way ?

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: since m can depend on (or not?), choose $m\ge 2^n(b-a)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any integer $m$, we have equivalence $a+\frac{m}{2^n}\geq b\ \Leftrightarrow\ m\geq2^n(b-a)$

Now as ${\mathbb R}$ is Archimedean, there is a natural number $m$ higher than the actual  $2^n(b-a)$

Answer (score 0):

What? Just solve for $m$. $m \geq (b-a)\cdot2^n$. In particular $m = (b-a)\cdot2^n$, or $m=(b-a)/2^n + 35$ will do.

Comment: As of right now, your answer is too short to be of much use. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: You may want to check the algebra: division vs. multiplication.

Comment: @Educ you asked me to "show there exists an $m$." I gave you an $m$ satisfying your requirements. You're going to have to elaborate your question quite a bit before I can know how to elaborate my answer...