# $I_{n}=\left[a+\frac{(k_n-1)}{2^n};\ a+\frac{k_{n}}{2^n}\right]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

> Let $ \mathcal{P} \subset  \mathbb{R}$,\ $\mathcal{P}\neq  \emptyset $ and let $b$ be an upper bound of  $\mathcal{P}$.
>
> 1. Let $a \in \mathcal{P}$ and let $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ Show that : 
>      $$\exists\ m\in\mathbb{N} \text{ such that: } \quad a+\dfrac{m}{2^n}\geq b$$
> 2. Deduce that : $\exists\ k_n \in \mathbb{N}\quad a+k_n\times\dfrac{1}{2^n}\ $  is  upper bound of  $\mathcal{P}$  while : $\ a+(k_{n}-1)\dfrac{1}{2^n}\ $ is not .
>
> $3$. Let  $$I_{n}=\left[a+\dfrac{(k_n-1)}{2^n};\ a+k_{n}\times\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right]$$
>   Show that:
>   $\hspace{3cm} \text{i)}\ I_{n+1}\subset I_n\qquad \text{ii)}\ \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}I_n=\{s\}\qquad \text{iii)}\ s=\sup\mathcal{P}  $

Answer for 1 question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032844/show-exists-m-in-mathbbn-text-such-that-quad-a-dfracm2n-geq-b#1032952)
Answer for 2 question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033027/for-every-n-there-exists-k-n-in-mathbbn-such-that-ak-n-2n-is-an-uppe)

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions 1 and 2 have been answered already, so I try to answer the third one. Since $\mathcal P$ is a bounded non-empty set, its supremum $S:=\sup\mathcal P$ exists.
Since $a+\frac{k_n}{2^n}$ is an upper bound of $\mathcal P$, while $a+\frac{k_n-1}{2^n}$ is not, we must have
\begin{align}
a+\frac{k_n}{2^n}\geq S>a+\frac{k_n-1}{2^n},\qquad(1)
\end{align}
which implies
$$
k_n\geq2^n(S-a)>k_n-1,\qquad n\in\mathbb N.\qquad(2)
$$
From (2) we get 
\begin{align*}
k_{n+1}&\geq 2^{n+1}(S-a)>2k_n-1 \\
k_{n+1}-1&<2^{n+1}(S-a)\leq2k_n
\end{align*}
and therefor
\begin{align*}
2k_n-1\leq k_{n+1}\leq 2k_n.\qquad (3)
\end{align*}
Note that each $k_n$ is a natural number. Now, (3) implies
\begin{align*}
a+\frac{k_{n+1}-1}{2^{n+1}}&\geq a+\frac{k_n-1}{2^n} \\
a+\frac{k_{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}&\leq a+\frac{k_n}{2^n},
\end{align*}
and this shows $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$, which is part (i).

Since $\left(a+\frac{k_n}{2^n}\right)-\left(a+\frac{k_n-1}{2^n}\right)=\frac{1}{2^n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, we obtain, using (i), that the nested intervals $I_n$ have (only) one common point $s$, and this shows (ii).

From (ii) we know that the $I_n$ shrink to one point $s$, that is, the left and right boundaries of $I_n$ both converge to $s$, i.e. $\frac{k_n}{2^n}\to s$ and $\frac{k_n-1}{2^n}\to s$. But then both the left and the right hand side of (1) (which are exactly those boundaries) converge to $s$, and this gives $s\geq S\geq s$ and hence $s=S$ as desired. This shows (iii).

Comment: Thank you this is good explanation! if you just could answer 1 and 2 her http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032844/show-exists-m-in-mathbbn-text-such-that-quad-a-dfracm2n-geq-b#1032952   and for 2 here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033027/for-every-n-there-exists-k-n-in-mathbbn-such-that-ak-n-2n-is-an-uppe  i'll accepted you have best explanation

Comment: I have read through your own ideas of question 1 and 2, and I must admit that I like them more than the given answers. So your solutions to 1 and 2 work perfectly, and there is absolutely no need for me to repeat in my answers, what you already found out. Good job! :)

Comment: Thanks so much but just write with your own style i'll accepted :)

Comment: Thats very kind of you, but as I said, I would have done it exactly as you actually have done it, so copy and paste your answers to here and voilà: Then you have mine ;)