# The supermum of E

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $f\ [0,1]\longrightarrow [0,1]$ be increasing function. let: $$E=\{x\in [0,1] \mid f(x)\geq x \} $$
>
> Show that $E$ has a supermum $b$ and that $f(b)= b$.

we have  $x\leq 1$ since $f$ is inceasing $f(x)\leq f(1)$
and $x\leq f(x)$

i don't know how to answer that question
any help would be apppreciated

Comment: I don't get it, if $f$ is increasing, then it must be the case that $f(1)$ is the largest value, if you could find a value $f(a < 1) \geq f(1)$ this would contradict the assumption that $f$ was increasing (it should be $\geq$ because the function is _increasing_, not _non-decreasing_).

Comment: it's just typo check my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $0\in E$, since $f(0)\geq0$, so $E$ is not empty. Moreover, since $E\subset[0,1]$, it is bounded. Thus, $b:=\sup E$ exists. Then we find a sequence $(x_n)\subset E$ with $x_n\to b$ and $x_n\leq b$. Since $f$ is increasing, $f(b)\geq f(x_n)\geq x_n\to b$, so $f(b)\geq b$. If $b=1$, then $f(1)=1$, since $f(1)\leq 1$. Otherwise ($b<1$) we have $f(x)<x$ for each $b<x<1$, and again since $f$ is increasing, we have for these $x$ that $f(b)\leq f(x)<x$. Letting $x\to b$ finally yields $f(b)=b$.

Comment: great explanation i like detail thank you

Comment: youre welcome :)

Comment: could you see this please  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033541/i-n-lefta-dfrack-n-12n-a-dfrack-n2n-right

Comment: I did. Please check my answer and ask in case of any question appearing.

Comment: why $f(1)\leq 1$

Comment: $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$

Comment: my question is it in general we have sup E=b implies that \exists a sequence $(x_n$)\subset $E$ and the same for inf E Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes. If $b=\sup E$, then we can get arbitrarily close to $b$ with elements of $E$, that is, there is a sequence $(x_n)\subset E$ st $x_n\to b$. The same for $\inf E$.

Comment: Your are welcome :)